# How to dynamically generate a map in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code

```
records.map do |record|
  {
    id: record.id,
    uuid: record.uuid
  }
end
```

but I would like portions of it to be created dynamically, i.e if I had the array `COLUMNS = ["id", "uuid", "name"]`

How could I have it generate the below based on the array automatically?

```
records.map do |record|
  {
    id: record.id,
    uuid: record.uuid,
    name: record.name
  }
end
```

i.e.

```
records.map do |record|
  {
    COLUMNS[0]: record.COLUMNS[0],
    COLUMNS[1]: record.COLUMNS[1],
    COLUMNS[2]: record.COLUMNS[2]
  }
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `record` an `ActiveRecord` model?

Comment: @nathanvda yup!

Answer (score 2):

**serializable_hash**

You can convert any ActiveRecord objects to a Hash with serializable_hash and you can convert any ActiveRecord results to an Array with to_a, like below

```
records = YourModel.all
# for all fields 
records.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)

# for specific fields
COLUMNS = ["id", "uuid", "name"]
records.to_a.map{ |r| r.serializable_hash(only: COLUMNS) }
```

for more info

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Comment: This is very interesting imho. However you are not explaining in your answer how this would solve the problem the OP has?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like below

```
    def generate_map(record)
      testing = {}
      COLUMNS.each do |column|
        testing[column.to_sym] = record[column.to_sym]
      end
      return testing
    end

    records.map do |record| generate_map(record) end
```

Comment: Glad you worked it out. This seems unnecessarily verbose, though; might be better to use some of what Ruby gives you.

Comment: Yes nice solution. I would make it even more generic, by writing something like `records.map {|record| generate_map(record, [:id, :uuid, :name]) }` which would not rely on the constant `COLUMNS` (and this way you could use for more instances/types of records?). But maybe in your case that is not needed.

Comment: Any tips appreciated! First time working in Ruby after years of python/javascript

Comment: I noticed you said that the `records` are from an `ActiveRecord` model. Therefore, it is not necessary to go this deep in the solution. The rails framework already have a one-liner designed to accomplish what you want, instead of these 8 liners :). You can find right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336944/7644846

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be something like this:

```ruby
records.map do |record|
  COLUMNS.map do |column|
    [column.to_sym, record.public_send(column)]
  end.to_h
end
```

It would make more sense to store the column names as `Symbol`s than as `String`s, since `Symbol` is Ruby's standard data type for "labels of things".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ruby 2.1:

```
records.map { |x| [x, x] }.to_h
```

Also, if I wrote:

```
records = ["id", "uuid", "name"]
puts records.map { |x| [x, x + " value"] }.to_h
```

The results is:

```
{"id"=>"id value", "uuid"=>"uuid value", "name"=>"name value"}
```

if you are using older versions of Ruby, you could use inject/reduce.

Comment: You might have to think this answer through a little more. How are you limiting the set of columns (with values) from a record with this solution?

Comment: Yea the question was edited so my answer doesn't quite make sense anymore

Answer (score 0):

You could surely improvise a bit.

```
COLUMNS = ["id", "uuid", "name"]

records.map do|record|
    result = {}
    COLUMNS.each{|column| result.merge!({column => (record.send(column) rescue '')})}
    result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see you answered that **the record is an `ActiveRecord` model** already.

Therefore, we have a very easy and simple way to accomplish that.

```rb
COLUMNS = [:id, :uuid, :name]
Record.select(*COLUMNS).map(&:serializable_hash)
```

In which `Record` is your ActiveRecord model.

You just need to select these `COLUMNS` from the `Record` and convert them to hashes.

References:

1. https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select
2. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html
3. https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/6796/arrays-and-the-splat-----operator